# How can 2 .net executables call functions on eachother?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

if I have 2 seperate .net executables how would one exe call functions on the other one?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Do you mean if one of the executables references the other, or are you talking about [inter process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) where two running processes communicate with each other?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Some kind of messaging or simply a method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET executables are still assemblies. From VS2008 onwards, it is trivial to add a reference to a .NET exe (in VS2005 you have to use command-line for this). So simply ensure that the target exe exposes some **public** classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile("pathtoYourExe");
Type myType = ass.getType ("Full name of type whose method you need to call");
myTypeName inst = (myTypeName) Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

But if you want to call methods of runnning application - use WCF or .NET remoting.